# Java BigDecimal divideAndRemainder throws Division impossible exception

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Check out this code. It works for number like 704 but from 705 starts getting a Division Impossible error:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    BigDecimal totalDuration = new BigDecimal(705);

    int scale = 2;
    MathContext mc = new MathContext(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(totalDuration.divideAndRemainder(new BigDecimal(5), mc));
  }
}
```

I'm using JDK 11.

Error thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division impossible
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.divideToIntegralValue(BigDecimal.java:1880)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.java:2012)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked documentation for `BigDecimal.divideAndRemainder`?

It says:

> throws **ArithmeticException** if the result is inexact but the rounding mode is UNNECESSARY, or mc.precision > 0 and *the result of this.divideToIntgralValue(divisor) would require a precision of more than mc.precision digits.*

So `int scale = 2;` is just not enough for this operation, if you change it to `int scale = 3;`, it works nice.

Answer (score 1):

705 / 5 == 141, and 141 can't be represented as as 2 digits.

The docs say:

> ArithmeticException is thrown if the integer part of the exact quotient needs more than precision digits.

(Mildy paraphrased)

You need to have more precision. It works when `scale` is 3.

704 works presumably because the integer portion *can* be represented as two digits: `1.4E+2`.

Comment: Yes but for whatever reason if you changed 705 to 700, it works!

Comment: `700` divide `5` gives you `140`, and `140` you can be represent as two digits - `1.4E+2`